# SharpDevelop XSHD file for Powershell syntax?

Tags: powershell, syntax-highlighting, sharpdevelop

Has anyone written an AvalonEdit XSHD file for PowerShell syntax? I'm in need of one for my project and I want to make sure I'm not inventing the wheel. Thanks

Comment: How can I get a copy of the .xshd that you created? Is it on the web somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only PowerShell syntax highlighting for AvalonEdit that I am aware of is the one in [PowerShell Workbench](http://powershellworkbench.codeplex.com/)

Comment: thanks. I ended writing one myself before seeing your answers. I'll check out the file in Powershell Workbench and may as well use it instead of mine.